# Uniform grid of points on SO(3)

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, computational-geometry

I would like to place $N$ equally spaced points on $SO(3)$ (or approximately equally spaced points). Here, every "point" refers to a rotation, and $N$ is user-specified.

I came across the Fibonacci sphere algorithm from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127012/8696224), which distributes points evenly on the sphere $S^2$. I am wondering if that idea can be extended to $SO(3)$.